# Reduce Wallet Sync Time

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, synchronization

So I am new to Bitcoin and I run the Bitcoin Core on my computer. I know that you need to wait for your wallet to sync before you can make transactions, but it says it won't finish syncing for 4 years.

I'm not sure if this is a problem and if there is a way to fix it, or I just need to suck it up and wait  for it to finish syncing. I am trying to learn how to mine and I know that I can't use a lite wallet (sorry if that's not what it is called) because large transactions will clog it up. Is there a way that I can fix this or should I just use an online wallet? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "four years" is a description of how far back in time the current synchronization progress is, it won't literally take four years to complete. For most people it will take under a day to completely sync from cold, and there's not really any way of speeding it up.